# Handling system alerts in Xcode UI tests

Tags: ios, xcode

How do you test for a system alert in an Xcode UI test, for example when accessing Itunes from an app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to first use a UI interruption handler, as described [here](https://github.com/joemasilotti/UI-Testing-Cheat-Sheet#handling-system-alerts).

```
  addUIInterruptionMonitorWithDescription("Sign In") { (alert) -> Bool in
    alert.buttons["Cancel"].tap()
    return true
  }
  app.otherElements["  Upgrade"].tap()
  app.tap()
```